# Future.then() is executed too early

Tags: dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a method which is supposed to return a `Future`, containing a list of groups.
This works fine as I can loop the list of groups in that method itself, but somehow `list` is returned before it could be filled. Surely this is an error on my part but I can't seem to grasp what I'm doing wrong.

```
Future< List<GroupData> > getGroups(String uniqueUserID) async
    List<GroupData> groups = new List<GroupData>();

    try {
      var result = Firestore.instance
          .collection("groups")
          .where("members", arrayContains: uniqueUserID);

      result.snapshots()
          .listen (
            (data) {
              // Handle all documents one by one
              for (DocumentSnapshot ds in data.documents)
              {
                List<String> members = new List<String>();
                for (dynamic member in ds.data['members'])
                {
                    members.add( member );
                }

                groups.add( new GroupData(ds.data['name'], ds.data['description'], ds.documentID.toString(), ds.data['admin'], members) );
              }
            }
          );

    } catch (exception)
    {
        print ('Something went wrong while fetching the groups of user ' + uniqueUserID + ' !');
    }

    return groups;

  }
```

This method is being called using the method `Future.then()` but the list is empty while there should be several resuls (and there are, I can loop all items in the list in the above method and access/print their data). What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The execution of your function is never locked. It doesn't wait until your listened stream finished.

There are a few solutions:

- change `stream.listen` into `await for (final item in stream)`
- add an `await stream.done`

Example:

before:

```dart
Stream<List<T>> stream;

stream.listen((list) {
  for (final item in list) {
    print(item);
  }
});
```

after:

```dart
await for (final list in stream) {
  for (final item in list) {
    print(item);
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm still not getting it quite right (though the issue is resolved). Would you mind providing me with an example of using `await for`? The example doesn't have to be using my code.